# Failed to install zbar with pip on Windows

Tags: python, pip, zbar

I'm trying to install `zbar` on my Windows x64 machine:

```
pip install zbar
```

And this is what I got:

```
Collecting zbar
Using cached zbar-0.10.tar.bz2
Installing collected packages: zbar
Running setup.py install for zbar ... error
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ruiyang\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-t2okcg\\zbar\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ruiyang\appdata\local\temp\pip-4pohzw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'zbar' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
C:\Users\Ruiyang\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tczbarmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\zbarmodule.obj
zbarmodule.c
c:\users\ruiyang\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-t2okcg\zbar\zbarmodule.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zbar.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Ruiyang\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ruiyang\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-t2okcg\\zbar\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ruiyang\appdata\local\temp\pip-4pohzw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ruiyang\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-t2okcg\zbar\
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to install `zbar` package with `pip`. When doing so, `pip` downloads the source and tries to compile the C/C++ source code of this project.

To do such a thing, you need a C/C++ compiler and having all dependencies. It may be complicated to have `pip` compiles this package.

The other solution is to download a binary wheel that embeds all binaries. `zbar` developers propose to download a binary wheel from their [GitHub webpage](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64/releases)

You can download this [binary wheel](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64/releases/download/v0.10/zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl), that targets a Windows Python 2.7 64 bit installation.

All you have to do is:

- open a Windows cli with `Windows+R` and by running inside `cmd`
- go to the directory where you have downloaded the `whl` file, with `cd` instructions
- run `pip install zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

For example, the command can be

```
pip install zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

If you have several Python installations, make sure to use the correct `pip` program.

You can do it for any package with some code that has to be compiled

Comment: zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. This is the error I am getting. I am trying hard to install zbar in my Win 7, 64bit Python 2.7. Kindly help.

Comment: Please look at the output of `python --version`, it should not be 2.7 with 64 bit. It could be 2.7 with 32 bit. Download the corresponding wheel

Comment: only 3
zbar-0.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is available , on option to support python3