# windows: pip install zbar cannot open include file and failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, windows, zbar, nao-robot, choregraphe

I need to install the zbar-library because I need it to use the qrtools-library in Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

When I run `pip install zbar` in the windows shell I get the following response: [image]

I already followed [this lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153688/failed-to-install-zbar-with-pip-on-windows) but it didn't worked.

Downloading a C/C++ Compiler didn't changed anything. Then I downloaded the linked binary wheel, but then I got on my shell the following response: 
[image]

How can I install zbar?

---

Edit: I need to use the qrtools library on a nao robot. I tried to install pip using putty. I tried the way described by Jordan B. ([look here](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/1506))So I downloaded the python file and uploaded it to the robot per File Transfer(Choregraphe). When I call `python get-pip.py --user` I get this error: [image]
How can I install zbar and pip on the robot?

Comment: You should probably create separare questions for installing it on windows, and installing it on NAO ...

Answer (score 0):

About NAO, I cross-compiled it using qibuild and made a service (as of NAOqi services) out of it : https://github.com/SoftBankRoboticsEurope/barcodereader